# Загрузка файла на сервер в фоновом режиме с возможность дозагрузки

Tags: java, servlet, rest, upload

Привет, подскажите как можно осуществить загрузку файла в фоновом режиме, то есть пользователь может выбрать файлы нажать загрузить и переходить по другим страницам сайта, при этом загрузка продолжается. А также если сбросилось соединение с сервером, то он может продолжить дозагрузку с того же места. Какие технологии нужно использовать? REST? Servlet? Возможно ли это?

Comment: Это возможно но не в обычных браузерах. Для этого необходим отдельный функционал, отдающий файл с места где было сделано прерывание, или с последнего переданного блока и на сервере и у клиента.

Answer (score 0):

REST и Servlet - это серверные технологии, они работают на стороне сервера. То что вы хотите должно работать на стороне клиента.

Браузеры не поддерживают такой функционал. Вам придется написать свой браузер или написать свое расширение для браузера.